# Facebook Feed dialog popup opens on the right side of page

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm using the Facebook feed dialog on my website  to share some content on users profile. This works fine, but the dialog popup opens all the time on the right side of the webpage. Is it possible to position this popup to the center of the screen?

Thanks!

Comment: welcome,can you show your code?

Comment: Are you opening the popup as a window or within the page as overlay?